# How to DELETE With SELECT SUM() FROM Table GROUP BY

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table material

```
 - id int,
 - name varchar(50),
 - content text,
 - quantity double,
```

the query without using group by

```
1, product1, content1, 25
2, product2, content2, 4 
3, product1, content3, 35
4, product3, content4, 15
```

the query with group by and SUM quantity

```
 product1, content1, SUM(quantity) : 60
 product2, content2, SUM(quantity) : 4 
 product3, content4, SUM(quantity) : 15
```

for example, if i have sum quantity  = 0

```
 product1, content1, SUM(quantity) : 0
 product2, content2, SUM(quantity) : 4 
 product3, content3, SUM(quantity) : 15
```

I would remove all products that produce the sum quantity = 0. 
for example: remove product 1 from id =1 and product 1 from id = 3

```
1, product1, content1 
3, product1, content3
```

Comment: MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
DELETE t
FROM `material` t
INNER JOIN(SELECT s.name FROM `material` s
           GROUP BY s.name
           HAVING sum(s.quantity) = 0)
 ON(t.name = s.name)
```

Comment: Can you please explain what does `material` mean and how do `t` and `s` come from? I am new to SQL. Thanks!

Comment: `material` is just a table, as OP posted. `t` and `s` are called aliases.. they're just a "nickname" for the table, such that the optimizer will be able to differ from the inner `material` table and the outer one. @hmhuang